# Mean i.o Need to change the base url path

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Its a mean.io app.
I need my app to have a prefix of `'test_prefix'` in all my urls

But app should fetch the data from root path.

So have modified the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/test_prefix">`
Now the my html files and other resources are pointing to 
eg: `test_prefix/app/user.html` ect.. so the whole app breaks

What should I need to achieve the same